# WAGMI: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?' in NextJS mobile browser

Tags: javascript, mobile, next.js, ethereum, ethers.js

#### Is there an existing issue for this?

- [X] I have searched the existing issues

#### Package Version

0.8.6

#### Current Behavior

Un error happens when you try to setup wagmi and use it in an mobile browser with NextJS.
**SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'.**

#### Expected Behavior

Not throwing an error.

#### Steps To Reproduce

You can reproduce it using the example application (`yarn create wagmi`) and opening it in chrome or any browser from a mobile phone. I also created a vanilla NextJS project and setup wagmi configurations till I end up with an error. https://github.com/lucaford/wagmi-test

#### Link to Minimal Reproducible Example (CodeSandbox, StackBlitz, etc.)

It can be reproduced using the example application

#### Anything else?

Can it be that wagmi is not compatible with mobile browsers and I am missing something?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your linked repository on my mobile phone (Safari, iPhone SE 2nd generation, iOS 16.1.1) and it worked fine.

It might be that the current default Next configuration does not target the device you are testing on.

You can [configure Next to support specific browsers](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/supported-browsers-features) using [browserslist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist).